# How to add content to a worksheet by referencing its name in ruby using axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, axlsx, rubyxl

I have created a workbook with multiple worksheets using axlsx. I've also given names to each of the worksheets. Now, **I want to add content to one of the existing worksheets. Is there any way to reference the worksheet I want to add content to?** That would be the easiest way.

I've also read that somewhere that you could use another gem to read the excel file then modify it. Does it have to be one with read/write capabilities like rubyXL or can I use one gem to read and then use axlsx again to write on it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share the code you are referring to. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: did you have any progress? I'm trying to use the cell validations of one sheet with a domain inside another sheet, but no idea